# PHP json_encode function is not working on ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In page load I am calling this function

```
function myFunction(selectedCinemaID) {    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "show_details.php",
        data: {cinema_id: selectedCinemaID }
    }).done(function( show_list ) {
        console.log(show_list.length);

    });
```

And my code in show_details.php

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `show` WHERE cinema_id=2;";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if($result){
        $show_list = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        array_push ($show_list, array($row['id'], $row['cinema_id'], row['show_time']));   
    }
    echo json_encode($show_list);        
    } else {
        echo mysql_error();
    }
```

In my database I have only two row and three column but the length showed in the console is 64. But according to the database length should be 2. `console.log(show_list) output [["2","2","2014-11-01 01:00:00"],["3","2","2014-11-01 04:00:00"]]` but it seems everything here is treated as an array element or string.  What is wrong in this code?

Comment: Try adding contentType : "application/json" property to options of jquery .ajax to force the response encoding.

Comment: Enable `error_reporting`.

Comment: contentType : "application/json" for this still get same result

Answer (score 4):

You haven't told jquery that you're sending JSON. As such, it'll treat the json text that the server is sending as text. That means

```
    console.log(show_list.length);
```

is outputting the length of the json string, not the count/size of the array you're building in PHP.

You need either

```
$.getJSON(....);
```

or

```
$.ajax( 
    dataType: 'json'
    ...
)
```

However, note that if your mysql query fails for any reason, then outputting the mysql error message as your are will cause an error in jquery - it'll be expecting JSON, and you could potentially be sending it a mysql error message, which is definitely NOT json.

Once you switch to JSON mode, you should never send anything OTHER than json:

```
if (query ...)
    output json results
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('error' => mysql_error()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript function .length is counting the length of the entire serialized array string. You need to parse it first:

```
.done(function( show_list ) {
    var data = JSON && JSON.parse( show_list ) || $.parseJSON( show_list );
    console.log( data.length );
});
```

Thanks,

Andrew